# C# DataRow all itemarrays to single string, appending | to each array

Tags: c#

```
 DataTable tblData = new DataTable();
                MySQLProcessor.dtTable(pullDataQuery, out tblData);
                foreach (DataRow columnRow in tblData.Rows)
                {
                  //do string work here
                }
```

columnRow looks like this
[0]Apple
[1]Pear
[2]Mango

I want to turn it into a string that looks like Apple|Pear|Mango
without doing a foreach loop in the array.

Soryr for not making it clear, each table comes out with a different amount of arrayitems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing

```
object[] arr = new object[] {"1", "2" };
string joinedStr = string.Join("|",arr.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
```

So, your code could become

```
     DataTable tblData = new DataTable();
              string myStr = string.Empty; 
                    MySQLProcessor.dtTable(pullDataQuery, out tblData);
                    foreach (DataRow columnRow in tblData.Rows)
                    {
                      myStr = string.Join("|",columnRow.ItemArray.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
                      //do whatever you want
                    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). The columns values in question must be extracted first, perhaps...

```
var cols = row.ItemArray
    .Select(i => "" + i) // Not i.ToString() so when i is null -> ""
    .ToArray(); // For .NET35 and before, .NET4 Join takes IEnumerable

var res = string.Join("|", cols);
```

...or similar.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Mike you can do something like this

```
string finalString=string.Empty;

foreach (DataRow columnRow in tblData.Rows)
                {
           finalString+=columnRow["ColumnName"]+"|";
                }
if(finalyString.length>0)
{
finalyString=finalString.Substring(0,finalString.length-1) // this removes extra "|" at the end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Without Using LINQ. In case you use old DotNet (Eg.2.0)
string ArrToStr(DataRow r,string separator)
{
   string temp = "";
   Object[] o = r.ItemArray;
   foreach(Object oo in o)
   {
     temp += oo.ToString() + separator;
   }            
   return temp;
}
//So you can use like this.
string value="";
foreach (DataRow row in combine.Rows)
{
   value += ArrToStr(row, ",") ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]:

You can get all the values of DataRow by it's property ItemArray.
ItemArray is array of values which data types are types of object.

You can pass this array to function string.Join() which concatenates all the elements of array, using the specified separator between each element.

Be carefull because if your DataRow contains DBNull.Value in any of the columns, function string.Join() will implicity convert DBNull.Value into empty string (""). So in the end you can get something like this A||B.
To avoid this situation I used in my example LINQ function Where() to get rid of empty values of DataRow and turn it into array again by using LINQ function ToArray(). More about DBNull.Value.ToString() you can find here [msdn source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_DBNull_ToString) .

In foreach loop you can notice that I have used dollar sign - $ (special character which identifies interpolated string), which is used for string interpolation.

> "String interpolation is the process of evaluating a string literal
> containing one or more placeholders, yielding a result in which the
> placeholders are replaced with their corresponding values"

In this case placeholder is enclosed in a pair of curly brackets {}.
By using string interpolation I got rid of another + sign operator for concatenating  string literal "\r\n".

```
string str = "";
    
foreach (DataRow columnRow in tblData.Rows)
{
    str += $"{string.Join("|", columnRow.ItemArray.Where(val => val != DBNull.Value).ToArray())}\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Code answers without an explanation are usually not well received by the community.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
string record = columnRow[0].ToString() + "|" + columnRow[1].ToString() + "|" + columnRow[2].ToString();
```

Comment: What if there r more than three items?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, see my edit, each table comes back with different arrays

Comment: Hmm...why the downvote?  My answer was based on the OP's original question, where the row had 3 columns....

Comment: @Tim , i didn't down vote , yours but your answer is hardcoded right , what happens if there are 100 rows? you should definetly loop through his existing loop and concatinate the string with "|" symbol

Comment: @Kobe - you have a valid point.  I was simply providing a quick answer specific to the poster's question.  He was wanting to avoid doing a foreach loop on the array, and I don't see any easy way to avoid some sort of loop if the number of columns aren't known ahead of time.  I'm curious to see what the answer is eventually.